# How to get messages from group posts?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have problem with scraping posts from Facebook group.
I tried some combination of python code with selenium but without result.

[post group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dnxH.png)

I tried this:

```
posts = self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class," ")]")
```

or

```
posts = self.browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[style=text-align: start;]")
```

Problem is with
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "div[style=text-align: start;]" is invalid: SyntaxError: Document.querySelectorAll: 'div[style=text-align: start;]' is not a valid selector;**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

def getDriver():
    user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0'}
    service = Service(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

    return driver

def login():
    driver = getDriver()
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
    driver.maximize_window()

    # filling the form
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email').send_keys("")
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'pass').send_keys("")
    # accept cookie button
    driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(string(), 'Allow all cookies')]")[0].click()

    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'login').click()
    return driver
def scrape():
    driver = login()
    driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/groups/119377711454891/')
    posts = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[style=text-align: start;]")
    print(posts.count())
    poster_names = driver.find_elements(
        By.XPATH, "//a[@data-hovercard-referer]")  #

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape()
```

Comment: what is the error message or problem?  the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ok, i forget for example

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: message from groups you can scrape as     for posts in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[dir="auto"][style="text-align: start;"]'):
        print(posts.text)